# Apex 5.0 : Action on buttons ? Get value from textfield?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

The first problem is that I have a button. I created a process called nextweek( to get data for next week from reservation table). I tried this The PL/SQL only as a trial:

```
begin
  if :RESERVNO is null then
    select RESERVNO
      into :RESERVNO
      from reservation;
  end if;
end;
```

but the page keeps telling me "NO DATA FOUND". I would like to create a report with the result of my PL/SQL Query

My second problem is that I want to take values from a textfield and use it in my PL/SQL Query in another button as the "ACCEPT" in oracle.

Comment: try to include your code to your post.

Comment: which code? I just wanna know how to make a report based on a query in apex 5.0 .This query needs a value entered by the user(into a text field). i would like to create a button, when it's pressed, the value inside the text field is taken by the query to run.. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need following:

1. Create report: click `Create new page` button (or `create region` if you already have a page), then choose region type `Report`. Write your source SQL query in the field `Region source` (choose `Source type` - `SQL Query`).
2. Create an item (textfield). For example, with the name `P_MY_ITEM`
3. Create a button. Here you don't need to change default properties. (Action on button click should be `Submit page`)
4. Add this item name to the source query in the region. It should look like:

   `select column1, column2, column3
     from table1, table2, table3
    where column4 = :P_MY_ITEM
      and <other conditions>`

After that, user can write something to the input field and press the button, page will be reloaded, and report will be changed accordingly to the item value.

Comment: thank you for your help.. I will try it... I have another question though : how can i create a trigger when i input on  a form??

Comment: @sylviehelou Triggers are created in database, not in apex. I think you should create new question and describe there what you want to get.

Comment: So I create a trigger in the database and then i create a form based on it? And How can I create this trigger with sql developer?

Comment: @sylviehelou Do you really know what trigger is? It looks like no. Trigger is a small program, which runs by database when certain event in the database happens. You don't need web page to use triggers.